# Docker: running a command after init on centos7 container with systemd

Tags: docker, centos7

According to https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/
the Centos7 container must be run with a init process to correctly get systemd working

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

I want to be able to run a script automatically when i call "docker run" so I changed the CMD line to

```
COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init", "/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

When I docker exec'd into the container i see the process

```
root         1     0  0 18:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/init /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
```

Despite the above line showing startup.sh along with init, the script, starup.sh, itself  was never executed because the script is supposed to start a couple of daemons, and i dont see them running after "docker run".
When I run the script manually (not as part of CMD line, but actually executing it inside of container shell), I would see the daemons running

How can I automate startup.sh to be called? I cannot simply replace CMD line only startup.sh because then systemd would break (I need the script to be called after init is running)

I tried to put /usr/sbin/init inside of startup.sh

ie startup.sh

```
daemon &
daemon2 &
exec /usr/sbin/init
```

but the daemons couldnt be run because init was not running

if you put

```
/usr/sbin/init &
daemon &
daemon2
```

this wouldnt work because init does not have PID of 1

Answer (score 0):

You do only need a systemd-init thing if you do run services. Otherwise you could just run a shell script and put daemon and daemon2 in the background.

In the case that you would really "systemctl start" something, then you could avoid the cgroup-mapping and systemd-init start ... just use the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script. It does also run as PID 1 if you like to.